# UIDatePickerView - Looks same as iOS 6 in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uidatepicker

Today in office I downloaded Xcode 5 and used UIDatePicker. It was way different then in iOS 6.

Now earlier on my iPhone, I had many app where I have used UIDatePicker. Just now I upgraded my iPhone to iOS 7 support.

Now when I open the earlier apps, I see that UIDatePicker is same as iOS 6 though on iPhone I have iOS 7. BUT for iOS 7, looks of UIDatePickerView is different.

What I was expecting is when I upgrade to iOS 7, I will see that UIDatePickerView in new style and not in old style

Any reason why I still see old style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI style that you see in the apps is based on the version of iOS that they are built against, not the version that they are running on. You can't choose with a setting on the picker.

Comment: Do you know why the UIAlertView when running in iOS 7 device is shown with the new style even if we build the application with and sdk prior to iOS 7 ?

Comment: Not all UI elements are born equal. UIAlertView is special because it can be presented by the application and the system. It would be weird if they had different style.

Comment: one quick question then... if I build app with xcode 5 (base sdk 7.0) and open in iPhone where I have skd 6.0, how datepicker will look like? like old way?

Comment: Yes, because the device doesn't know about the new UI style (just like old devices don't know about collection views).

Answer (score 0):

If an application is compiled with an sdk prior to iOS 7 (The base sdk is iOS 6, 5,..) you will see the old style even if your are in a device that running in iOS. But if you compile witch Xcode 5 with the base SDK you will see the new style.